# How would you document an API routine that is initiated by the vendor (not the client)?

Tags: api, rest

We are developing a REST API and, in addition to various resources which developers can access, our application sends information to listener scripts on client servers.

Our API documentation lists all of the "Resources" which client applications can access. That part is easy.

But how should we list the various %???% in which our application will POST content to client listener scripts?

As developers, how would you expect these %???% to be named?

Thanks

Note 1: I've used %???% because I don't know what to call them.
Note 2: First time I post to stackoverflow, so apologies if I've failed to follow protocol.

**EDIT**

Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Our API receives requests from clients. It also sends requests to clients.

For example, when the client receives a message, we will send that message to their server. Or when the status of one of the messages they sent earlier have been updated, we send the update to their server.

Or, to use Twitter as example (imagining we were Twitter), that when you were mentioned in a tweet, we sent the details of that tweet to your server

When a client sends a request to our API, that is being described as "Accessing a Resource" and the documentation lists "Resources".

But what do we call it when our API sends a request to a client? e.g. API-Originated Method?

Comment: Just document what you're going to send and what the clients should listen for. I can't tell you what I'd expect them to be named because you don't say what you're doing.

Comment: If there is a `POST` there is probably a form.  The annotation `%???%` looks vaguely like PHP; is that what you are using?  Then maybe add the [php] tag.

Comment: I've updated the original post for improved clarity.

Comment: @Cfreak - You've almost understood my question. We are, of course, documenting the parameters etc. My question is more about organising the documentation. One section of the specifications is called "Resources" (i.e. what clients access on our API) and the other section (which deals with what we send to client servers) is called [FILL IN THE BLANK]

Comment: With all due respect you're over-thinking it. Take a look at [Paypal's NVP Documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_NVPAPIOverview) It is similar to what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. The term I am looking for is something like "callback", but callbacks apply as responses to previous API requests.

Answer (score 2):

Parameters?

I don't care how they are named as long as there is some convention to it!